# Did Dumbledore know the Marauders were unregistered animagi?

Tags: harry-potter

Is there any indication in the books that Dumbledore figured out (after the stunt Sirius pulled with Snape,  trapping him in the Whomping Willow with Moony maybe ) that the Marauders (sans Lupin) are animagi?

If yes, why didn't he encourage them to register?

Why risk an Azkaban senence, which is surely unhealthy, when you can register and transform whenever you please?

All Snape had to do in his death eater period is to warn the ministry there were three unregistered animagi about and let them face the investigation and the consequences if it was proven - and then Dumbledore would lose three order members.

He could have even saved them the trouble saying that they were learning how to turn into animals under his (or McGonagall's) supervision.

Comment: As edited, this is more than one question.

Comment: ...............And now? ;)

Comment: Well, if those lines were removed instead of crossed out, yes.

Comment: Um, you seem to be experienced about posting here. If my question is 'did Dumbledore knew x and if yes then why didnt he do y'? How i go about it? First i post the first part of the question and when answered, if the answer is yes then i post another one, that refers to the previous one?

Comment: I would say that a "Why didn't Dumbledore do X?" would be fine, nominally. Dumbledore did *not* know, however, as indicated in the new duplicate. So that pretty much explains why he didn't do anything.

Comment: Yes, that one was helpful.